# Colon Use or Not

Tags: commas, colons

> I listened to the song. It went:
>
> The man in the hat is crazy. The man in the hat is....

Should there be a colon after 'went'?

Or not?

Comment: You mean, is it still OK if you leave out the colon? I can't think of a reason why not, but let's hear what the experts have to say. Good question.

Comment: I think you should put the example sentences in a block quote though. Had to read the question three times before I knew which "went" you were asking about.

Comment: This is a quotative structure; zero punctuation, a comma or a colon is normally used after the quotative verb to introduce the quote (/text / lyrics). The colon is probably the best choice here. Because of the new-paragraph formatting typical of poems / song lyrics, no inverted commas are necessary (or desirable).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you. For example, when I'm filling the timesheet I used to write it down as below:

```
I have worked on below tasks today:
-task 1 
-task 2
```

And some people write it as

```
I have worked on these tasks 
-task 1
-task 2
```

But what I feel and prefer is to add the colon is the correct way to follow. Because in books they follow colon to show what character is saying, like

```
James: hi
Jhon: hello 

How we read it?

James says hi, Jhon says hello.
```